# My inputs are getting skipped when using gets

Tags: c, string, input, struct, structure

I can't take the input for the `name` of the book for the loops `i = 2` and `i = 3`.

It is getting skipped. The first input for `i = 1` is running absolutely fine.

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct book
{
    char name[100];
    float price;
    int pages;  
}bk;

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    bk b[100];
    // b1, b2, b3;
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter name of book %d: ",i);
        gets(b[i].name);
        printf("Enter price of book %d: ",i);
        scanf("%f",&b[i].price);
        printf("Enter pages of book %d:",i);
        scanf("%d",&b[i].pages);
    }
    printf("\nYour inputs are:");   
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        printf("\nName of book %d: %s",i,b[i].name);
        printf("\nPrice of book %d: %f",i,b[i].price);
        printf("\nPages of book %d: %d",i,b[i].pages);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to remember is to never use `gets` again, more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/6865932).

The second is to not mix `gets` (or rather `fgets`, which is what you should use to replace `gets`) and `scanf`.

The root of your problem is that in the second loop, `gets` reads the newline character left in the buffer by the `scanf` at the end of the loop, making it seems as though it was skipped, it was not, if you print `b[2].name` you'll see that it has a newline character.

Your code should look more like this:

```
void clear_buffer(){ //helper function to clear buffer when needed
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){}
    printf("Bad input, try again: ");
}
```

```
//...
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    bk b[100];
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter name of book %d: ", i);
        while(scanf(" %99[^\n]", b[i].name) != 1){ // mind the space before specifer
            clear_buffer(); 
        }
        printf("Enter price of book %d: ", i);
        while(scanf("%f", &b[i].price) != 1){
            clear_buffer(); // if the value was not parsed correctly, ask again
        }
        printf("Enter pages of book %d:", i);
        while(scanf("%d", &b[i].pages) != 1){
            clear_buffer();
        }
    }
    //...
    //rest of the code
}
```

The code has some improvements:

1. Using `scanf(" %99[^\n]", b[i].name)` makes sure that there will be no buffer overflow, it will read, at most 99 caracters, reserving a space for the null terminator, which is something `gets` cannot do, that's why it was removed from the language, though some compiler still support it, I can't immagine why.
2. I'm checking if the `scanf` really parses the values, if not, let's say someone inputs a character instead of a digit, it asks again, instead of entering an infinite loop which is what would happen before.
3. `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)` makes sure the array is being populated from index 0, the way you have it, it will not use the first element of the array, you'll have to fix the `printf` accordingly..

Answer (score -1):

you are reading some trash from stdin, you need to clean stdin with `setbuf(stdin, NULL);`. And for show the price you need only 2 decimal places, your program will be like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct book
{
    char name[100];
    float price;
    int pages;  
}bk;
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    bk b[100];
    // b1, b2, b3;
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter name of book %d: ",i);
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);
        gets(b[i].name);
        
        printf("Enter price of book %d: ",i);
        scanf("%f",&b[i].price);
        printf("Enter pages of book %d:",i);
        scanf("%d",&b[i].pages);
    }
    printf("\nYour inputs are:");   
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        printf("\nName of book %d: %s",i,b[i].name);
        printf("\nPrice of book %d: %.2f",i,b[i].price);
        printf("\nPages of book %d: %d",i,b[i].pages);
    }
    return 0;
}
```